# pg_dump gets SSL error, seems to time out

Tags: postgresql, ssl, pg-dump

I'm trying to download a database to my local machine using `pg_dump`. The command I'm using is:

```
pg_dump --host xx.xx.xx.xx --port xxxx --username "xxx" --password  --format custom --blobs --verbose --file "testing.db" "xxx"
```

When it gets to dumping the last table in the database it always crashes with this error:

```
pg_dump: Dumping the contents of table "versions" failed: PQgetCopyData() failed.
pg_dump: Error message from server: SSL error: sslv3 alert handshake failure
pg_dump: The command was: COPY public.xxx (columns) TO stdout;
```

I SSH'd into a server that's a bit closer to the server I'm downloading from (I'm in Brisbane, it's in San Francisco) and was able to do the `pg_dump` without issue. So I know the database server is fine. I suspect it's a timeout because it's getting to the last table before failing; if it was actually an SSL error I'd have expected it to come up sooner. That said, the timeout occurs after a different amount of time each time it fails (the two most recent tests failed after 1300s and 1812s respectively).

Any tips on how to debug are welcome.

I'm on OS X 10.8.5. Local pg_dump is 9.2.4, server is Ubuntu Server running psql 9.1.9.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It might be a **SSL renegociation** problem.

See this parameter on the server (`postgresql.conf`) and the associated warning about old SSL client libraries, although OS X 10.8 seems newer than this.

From the [9.1 documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/runtime-config-connection.html):

> **ssl_renegotiation_limit (integer)**
>
> ```
> Specifies how much data can flow over an SSL-encrypted connection before
> renegotiation of the session keys will take place.
> ```
>
> Renegotiation decreases an attacker's chances of doing cryptanalysis
>   when large amounts of traffic can be examined, but it also carries a
>   large performance penalty. The sum of sent and received traffic is
>   used to check the limit. If this parameter is set to 0, renegotiation
>   is disabled. The default is 512MB.
>
> Note: SSL libraries from before November 2009 are insecure when using SSL
>    renegotiation, due to a vulnerability in the SSL protocol. 
>    As a stop-gap fix for this vulnerability, some vendors
>   shipped SSL libraries incapable of doing renegotiation. If any such
>   libraries are in use on the client or server, SSL renegotiation should
>   be disabled.

**EDIT**:

Updating this parameter in `postgresql.conf` does not require a server restart, but a server reload with `/etc/init.d/postgresql reload` or `service postgresql reload`.

The value can be also be checked in SQL with `show ssl_renegotiation_limit;`

Even if the size of the dump is smaller than 512Mb, it may be that the amount of data transmitted is way larger, since `pg_dump` compresses the data locally when using the custom format (`--format custom`).

Comment: I tried setting this to 0, but still got the same error. (I didn't restart postgres as it did indicate in the .conf file that this was necessary, should I give that a go?) The db dump should be much less than 512mb for what that's worth.

Comment: OK thanks, I'll give that a go outside peak hours and let you know how it goes.

Comment: +1 because it solved the same problem for me, although in a much simpler environment (pg_dump and the database server were on the same debian 7.5 machine). I'd check this as the correct answer, based on the almost 1-hour long search I've done on this particular error message.

Comment: Also, FWIW I'd move this question over to serverfault. Just sayin'.